# Programming language features

Tags: haskell

Which features need to be present in a programming language such that it can  express any sequential computation which a computer can excute today? And what if the language is Haskell in specific

Comment: see [Truing completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) (I guess) - also way to broad sorry

Comment: There is no single fixed feature which *must* be present for a language to be Turing complete. Name your feature -- short of "Turing completeness" -- and I bet I can design you a Turing-complete language that does not have that feature. Given this, naming a set of features all of which must be present seems hopeless; and coming up with a short description of sets of features that result in Turing completeness doubly so.

Comment: @DanielWagner Well, it probably depends on what you mean by "feature". For example if non-termination is a feature then I bet that doesn't exist a single Turing-complete system without that "feature", in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Haskell is Turing complete.

My current beliefs have high weight on the outcome that any sound and complete description of "feature sets that guarantee Turing completeness" is either infinite or includes a non-terminating algorithm; so I believe it is not reasonable to expect an answer to your other question.